# How to update a particular point of a complex geometry in Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table which contains complex geometry, like `LINESTRING`, `POLYGONS` etc. By complex I mean any geometry that is not just a single `POINT`. Besides, I know there is a nice function in `Postgis` that can dump complex geometries into points:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom as dp FROM layer;
```

This query returns as many rows, as there are points in all geometries. But what if I want to update a particular point, without touching the whole geometry. Is it possible? It would be nice, if I could virtually replace one point returned by `ST_DumpPoints`, then collect all points and do the reverse procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is
[ST_SetPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_SetPoint.html) function you looking for.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I was looking exactly for this function! You saved my day!